# An ETA plugin for hangoutsbot

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps

This is a plugin for [hangoutsbot/hangoutsbot](https://github.com/hangoutsbot/hangoutsbot) that listens for words people say and then gives them an ETA and a link with directions.

Happy to hear about any optimisations that could be made.

```
import logging
import hangups
import plugins
import asyncio

import googlemaps

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

from textblob import TextBlob
from urllib.parse import quote

def _initialise(bot):
  plugins.register_handler(_handle_message, type="message")

def _handle_message(bot, event, command):
  raw_text = " ".join(event.text.split())
  directions = ["how", "long", "take", "to", "from"]
  if all(x in raw_text.lower() for x in directions):
      yield from _getdirections(bot, event, raw_text, directions)

@asyncio.coroutine
def _getdirections(bot, event, text, type):
  logger.info("Directions from text: " + text)
  try:
      mapskey = bot.get_config_option("maps_api_key")
  except:
      logger.error("Something went wrong getting the API key. Check it and reload.")
      return
  if not mapskey.startswith("AIza"):
      logger.error("Your API key is wrong, apparently. Check it and reload.")
      return

  bicycling = ["by bicycling","via bicycling", "by cycling","via cycling", "by bike","via bike", "a bicycle", "to cycle"]
  walking = ["on foot", "by walking","via walking", "to walk", "by foot","via foot"]
  transit = ["by public transport","via public transport"]
  train = ["by train","via train"]
  bus = ["by bus","via bus"]
  subway = ["by subway", "on the subway", "by the subway", "via subway", "via the subway"]
  tram = ["via tram", "via light rail","by tram", "by light rail","on the tram", "on the light rail"]

  try:
      regionbias = bot.get_config_option("directions_geobias")
  except:
      regionbias = ""

  routeMode = "driving"
  transitMode = ""

  logger.info("text:" + text)
  text = TextBlob(text)
  for s in text.sentences:
    if any(x in s for x in transit):
        routeMode = "transit"
        for f in transit:
            s = s.replace(f, "")
    elif any(x in s for x in bicycling):
        routeMode = "bicycling"
        for f in bicycling:
            s = s.replace(f, "")
    elif any(x in s for x in walking):
        routeMode = "walking"
        for f in walking:
            s = s.replace(f, "")
    elif any(x in s for x in train):
        routeMode = "transit"
        transitMode = "train"
        for f in train:
            s = s.replace(f, "")
    elif any(x in s for x in bus):
        routeMode = "transit"
        transitMode = "bus"
        for f in bus:
            s = s.replace(f, "")
    elif any(x in s for x in subway):
        routeMode = "transit"
        transitMode = "subway"
        for f in subway:
            s = s.replace(f, "")
    elif any(x in s for x in tram):
        routeMode = "transit"
        transitMode = "tram"
        for f in tram:
            s = s.replace(f, "")

      logger.info(s)
      if all(x in s.lower() for x in type):
          dFrom = s.lower().words.index(type[-1])
          dTo = [i for i, x in enumerate(s.lower().words) if x == type[-2]][-1]

          if dFrom + 1 < dTo:
              origin = " ".join(s.words[dFrom + 1:dTo])
              destination = " ".join(s.words[dTo + 1:])
          elif dTo + 1 < dFrom:
              destination = " ".join(s.words[dTo + 1:dFrom])
              origin = " ".join(s.words[dFrom + 1:])

          gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=mapskey)

          dirs = gmaps.directions(origin, destination, mode=routeMode, region=regionbias, transit_mode=transitMode)

          logger.info("origin/destination/mode/region/transit_mode:" + "/" + origin + "/"  + destination + "/" + routeMode + "/" + regionbias + "/" + transitMode)

          try:
              dirs1 = dirs[0]
              dirlegs = dirs1["legs"]
              dirleg = dirlegs[0]
              duration = dirleg["duration"]
              time = duration["text"]
              startAddr = dirleg["start_address"]
              endAddr = dirleg["end_address"]
              mapsUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps?f=d&saddr=" + quote(startAddr) + "&daddr=" + quote(endAddr)
              routeUrlParams = {"walking":"w","transit":"r","bicycling":"b"}
              logger.info(dirs1)
              logger.info(dirleg)
              logger.info(dirs)
              if routeMode: mapsUrl = mapsUrl + "&dirflg=" + routeUrlParams[routeMode]
              yield from bot.coro_send_message(event.conv, "Looks like it'll take you " + time + " to get from " + startAddr + " to " + endAddr + '. [<a href="' + mapsUrl + '" >maps</a>]')
          except IndexError:
              logger.error(dirs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long else if chains of repeated instructions are a bad idea, if you ever see them then you should immediately re-think the code, perhaps you could refactor it to work better. In this case, you definitely can. Here's what you're doing for `bicycling`:

```
elif any(x in s for x in bicycling):
    routeMode = "bicycling"
    for f in bicycling:
        s = s.replace(f, "")
```

But that's the same paradigm for all modes of transport:

```
elif any(x in s for x in transport_name):
    routeMode = "transport_name"
    for f in transport_name:
        s = s.replace(f, "")
```

Using the above code you could do all of them. Obviously you don't want to set `routeMode` to just `"transport_name"`, but there's an easy fix to get an accessible string. You should change your data from being multiple lists to be a dictionary of lists. This way you'll have string keys paired with your list values:

```
TRANSPORT = {
              "bicycling": ["by bicycling", "via bicycling", "by cycling",
                            "via cycling", "by bike","via bike",
                            "a bicycle", "to cycle"],
              "walking": ["on foot", "by walking", "via walking",
                          "to walk", "by foot","via foot"],
             }
```

And so on. Now you can loop over all the keys and lists in transport like so:

```
for sentence in text.sentences:
    for mode, phrases in TRANSPORT.items():
        if any(phrase in sentence for phrase in phrases):
            routeMode = mode
            for phrase in phrases:
                sentence = sentence.replace(phrase, "")
            break
```

Looping over `TRANSPORT.items()` allows you to get the key and the value from the dictionary simultaneously. So `mode` will be set as `bicycling` and `phrases` will be set as the list of bicycling strings. I also renamed some of your variables to be clearer. `sentence` and `phrase` are more readable than `s` and `f`. I also named `TRANSPORT` in UPPER_SNAKE_CASE to demonstrate that it's a constant value.

In addition, I would recommend using a regular expression instead of a loop with `replace`. You could build a regular expression using these lists with just `|` separating each phrase and passing them to [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub). This would mean that it'd match any occurrences of any of the phrases and replace them with an empty string because `|` is like an `or` in regular expressions. The useful part is that it can replace all possible phrases with just one call.

```
if any(phrase in sentence for phrase in phrases):
    routeMode = mode
    pattern = '|'.join(phrases)
    sentence = re.sub(pattern, '', sentence)
    break
```

(don't forget to `import re` for this to work)